# Animator onAnimationEnd cant change text

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm translating a TextView  500dp to the right of the screen and then I use a listener to listen for the animation end where I want to change the text and then translate the TextView back to its initial space.

My code is :

```
        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rvDownCircle, "x", 500f);
    animator.setStartDelay(500);
    animator.setDuration(1500);
    animator.start();
    animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            rvDownCircle.setText("New Label");
            ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rvDownCircle, "x", 0);
            animator.setDuration(1000);
            animator.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
```

The TextView is named rvDownCircle and as you can see when I'm on AnimationEnd I change the text to a new text - but what it happens is that text stays the same.

My question is : what am i doing wrong here and what should i change so when i reach the end of the animation setText will take effect.

Comment: no no no, use an `Interpolator` for that, f. ex. `CycleInterpolator`

Comment: CycleInterpolator to change the text ?

Comment: no, for animating your view back to the original position, ok i missed you are calling `setText` at the end of the first animation, if you want to do that this way try calling `animator.start();` after adding the listener

Comment: animation works as I expect. The only problem is why onanimationEnd text doesnt changes.